# UIBarButtonItem Custom Background Appearance 'Jumping' after flip transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

For some reason when I set a custom background image for the uibarbutton items:

```
UIImage *button30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar_button_orange.png"]
                     resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:button30 forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

My button is 'jumping' or updating it's width (or more accurately the padding on each side of the text) on a horizontal flip.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain handler:^(id sender) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Ignore the handler bit, I'm using BlocksKit.

You can see it happening here: http://screencast.com/t/HZRBS70OT6wt

#### Additional Info

It even does this when I put the button in place in storyboard's instead of code. Only seems to happen on the horizontal flip.

### Cause:

Apparently it has something to do with using a custom font. Almost like it's not calculating the width right at first.

## Sample Project

[Recreated the problem in this sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dw3w9sbvfp14wl5/sample.zip). Would love if someone knew how to fix this. Can't believe nobody has run into it.

Comment: Where are you running your self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem code, in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @PatrickTescher Yep in viewDidLoad.

Comment: It almost seems like its switching between a back button and a regular button. Maybe try seting setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the reason of this behavior, but setting image inset helps to fix this.
[image]

Comment: Awesome. That works. Going to leave it open a little while in case anyone knows the reason and a better solution, otherwise I'll mark this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to do ui modification in bar button its always better to initialize it with custom view.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:button30 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissFuction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Comment: Using UIBarButtonItems is totally acceptable. You don't need to add buttons for everything.

Comment: I also know this, but UIBarbutton is not very much open to customization

Comment: Plenty customizeable. Check out the appearance customization stuff introduced with iOS5