# UIBarButtonItem Custom Font Wrong Size (Updates on touch)

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6

You can see it happening here:

http://www.screencast.com/t/mSveqUgPe1

Similar to my question here: [UIBarButtonItem Custom Background Appearance 'Jumping' after flip transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261148/uibarbuttonitem-custom-background-appearance-jumping-after-flip-transition)

It appears to be entirely caused by setting a custom font for `UIBarButtonItem`s via the appearance api.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1.0],
  UITextAttributeTextColor,
  [UIColor colorWithRed:4/255.0 green:4/255.0 blue:4/255.0 alpha:0.5],
  UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)],
  UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Bold" size:16.0],
  UITextAttributeFont,
  nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If I comment out even just the font part it fixes the problem. Even using a non-custom font like Helvetica causes the same issue when set in this manner. The previous hack of adjusting the image offset doesn't work on this one, so trying to find another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly this is a bug, but I found a new workaround in code this time.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"NEXT";
}
```

Setting the title in code after calling `super viewWillLayoutSubviews` works. As to why that fixes it... no idea.

### Not quite

Now it's jumping. It renders wrong, then updates to the correct position/size.