# iOS navigationItem.titleView remove margins

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, titlebar

I have something like this:

[image: titleBar_image]

But I need that the view that am setting for the titleView, doesn't has those margins on the left and right side. Something like this:

[image: titleBar_image2]

This is what am actually doing:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) XHScrollMenu *scrollMenu; // where XHScrollMenu is a subclass of UIView

- (void)viewdidLoad{
 _scrollMenu = [[XHScrollMenu alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame];
 _scrollMenu.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 _scrollMenu.delegate = self;
 _scrollMenu.selectedIndex = 0;
 self.navigationItem.titleView =self.scrollMenu;
}
```

I tried giving the view a with of 320, but I got the same result. I read in other post, that maybe a subclass make the trick, but don't know how to implement that solution...

How can I make the title view use the entire width?

Comment: It might help if anything even called the method you posted.

Comment: I think you may find the solution in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914812/how-to-edit-empty-spaces-of-left-right-uibarbuttonitem-in-uinavigationbar-ios

Answer (score -1):

Try with `bounds` instead of `frame`. see [different between bounds and frame.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071112/uiviews-frame-bounds-center-origin-when-to-use-what)

```
...initWithFrame:self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds] /// or give frame manually such like CGRectMake(x,y,self.view.frame.size.width, yourHeight);
```

If this suggestion doesn't help you then sure problem under `initWithFrame` of `XHScrollMenu`. Go in this method and check there.