# How to change space between UIBarButtonItems in UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

This is how it looks now:

[image]

This is how it is represented in Debug view Hierarchy:

[image]

And here is how I set it up in code:

```
func setupUserAndCartButtons() {

    var rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem]()

    let cartBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: DBCart.sharedCart().icon, style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("cartButtonTapped:"))

    rightBarButtonItems.append(cartBarButtonItem)

    let userIcon = UIImage(named: "icon-user")
    let userBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: userIcon, style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("userButtonTapped:"))
    rightBarButtonItems.append(userBarButtonItem)

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = rightBarButtonItems
}
```

**Hot to move them closer to each other without using custom view?**

Comment: May be the width of the images you using is way too high for the UIBarButtonItem. You can also use the view instead and place your buttons as you wish. You may have some idea if you visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614562/change-spacing-between-uibarbuttonitems-in-ios-8

Answer (score 2):

use `imageInsets` property of UIBarButtonItem

**In Objective-C**
`[addContact setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10,0, 0)];`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.1**

```
 buttonName.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 30, 0, 0)
```

This will move button to right side to other button.
Hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

Add buttons using custom View:

```
  //MARK:Customize Navigation Bar
  func addButtonsToNavigationBar(){
    let cartButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton

    cartButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)
    cartButton.addTarget(self, action: "cartButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cartButton.setImage(UIImage(named: DBCart.sharedCart().icon), forState: .Normal)

    let cartBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: cartButton)

    let userButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    userButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)
    userButton.addTarget(self, action: "userButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    userButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon-user"), forState: .Normal)

    let userBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: userButton)

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems=[cartBarButtonItem,userBarButtonItem]
  }
```

Comment: Could you please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337217/add-space-to-image-leftbarbuttonitem-with-swift-3 ?

Answer (score 0):

UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace is used to adjust spacings of navigation bar items.

Example code:

```
- (void)setRightBarButtonItems {

    UIBarButtonItem *addTaskButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] bk_initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                    handler:handler];

    UIBarButtonItem *negativeSeperator = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];

    if ([UIDevice isIOS7Plus]) {
        negativeSeperator.width = -12;
    } else {
        negativeSeperator.width = -8;
    }
    UIBarButtonItem *separator = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    separator.width = 50;

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:@[addTaskButton, separator, [self filterButton]]];
}
```

Comment: the width for `.FixedSpace` doesn't change anything.. it still doesn't work.

Comment: well i am using it to adjust spacing of navigation bar items. here is screenshot: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=51rpts&s=8