# How to add spacing to Left BarButtonItem Image with Swift 3

Tags: swift3, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I would like to **add space to the left** of the bar button.
[image]

So, I add this code.

```
    navbar.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
    navbar.delegate = self

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green:49.0/255.0, blue:79.0/255.0, alpha:0.1)

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]

    navItem.title = prefs.value(forKey: "PROVIDER_NAME") as! String?
    let image = UIImage(named: "back_image")
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
```

After adding this code, the button image does not show well and looks no good. 
[image]

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: remove the `imageInsets` from your code

Comment: Bro @HamzaAnsari,    When I remove this, I got error of Cannot assign value of type 'UIEdgeInsets' to type UIBarButtonItem

Comment: i mean remove whole line

Comment: @HamzaAnsari, So, If I remove this code, how do I add space to the left of the bar button item?

Comment: well you dont need to add space to leftBarButton it already have insets

Comment: How you added barButton in your first image?

Comment: @HamzaAnsari   If I don't add space, the appearance is like the first image.

Comment: You may want to init UIBarButtonItem with custom view and set the desired frame. And then add your image to that view. As I showed here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18874211/744015

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546132/how-to-customize-the-navigation-back-symbol-and-navigation-back-text/43556837#43556837

Answer (score 3):

Hi Code given below might be useful for you.

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {
    class func itemWith(colorfulImage: UIImage?, target: AnyObject, action: Selector) -> UIBarButtonItem {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(colorfulImage, for: .normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 44.0, height: 44.0)
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -50, 0, 0)
        button.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)

        let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        return barButtonItem
    }
}
```

You can increase or decrease `Left Padding` for `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -50, 0, 0)` as per your requirement for left padding.

You can use above extension in your code as describe below.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.itemWith(colorfulImage: UIImage(named: "ic_back")?.withColor(UIColor.white), target: self, action: #selector(btnBackClicked))

func btnBackClicked() {
    print("your code here on back button tapped.")

}
```