# How to customize the navigation back symbol and navigation back text?

Tags: ios, storyboard, navigationbar

This is the back icon and back text now:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But if I want my navigation back like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I have tried to set the back to my want icon image:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But it useless.

Comment: are you trying to achieve `back button` with just `backArrow`?

Comment: @Joe, How to do with it?

Comment: so you want just `backArrow` nothing fancy ?

Comment: Did you see my update at the bottom with link?

Comment: glad I helped....

Comment: You can,once you place an barButtonItem to your  stoayBoard.Make an action IBOutlet connection to your destVC and paste backButtonTapped() code inside to your button action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can hide back button text in many ways.Try this simple approach.

**Step1:** Goto your `mainstoryBoard` and click `navigationBar`.

**Step 2:** Goto `Attributes Inspector` under `Navigation Item` add a **BLANK SPACE** in `Back Button`

[image]

**Step 3:** If you want to change `backButton` text method is pretty much the same.

[image]

**Update 1:** If you want to use an image as a back button check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504860/how-to-change-back-button-title-on-navigation-controller-in-swift3/40505660#40505660)

---

**Update 2:**

**Method 2:** Using custom image as a back button.

Paste below code into your `detailVC` and set image for your back Button.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   title = "Detail VC"

    let customButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped)) //
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = customButton  
}

func backButtonTapped() {     
   _ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)  
}
```

I am setting back button image in `assets catalogue` with the `32`pixel size.I am not sure about the asset image size.Check with `apple doc` about the size class.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, bro, but how can I change the back arrow to my customize icon?

Comment: can I set the back button image in storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `UIBarButton` and add it the `navigationItem.leftBarButton`.

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"yourImage"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(yourBackMethod(sender:))
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = = backButton


@objc internal func yourBackMethod(sender: AnyObject) {
  navigationController.popViewController()
}
```

Hope this helps.