# Strange behavior of custom back button in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, back-button

I am trying to change default back button in IOS Swift to custom one. What I get is that[image]

but should be that
[image]

How can it be fixed people?

Comment: can you show the code you are using?

Comment: @JoseQuintero sure. I add this in appdelegate didfinishlaunchingwithoptions

https://pastebin.com/NExMZkXh

Comment: The issue has to do with the image being stretched, take a look a this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34646201/7852085

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546132/how-to-customize-the-navigation-back-symbol-and-navigation-back-text/43556837#43556837

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard you can try using the "aspect fit" option or add aspect ratio to the button to make sure it has the correct scale according to the image.

Comment: i did it programaticaly, i dont think i can fix it on storyboard

Comment: with this you can do the same programmatically: button.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

Comment: i did it like here https://pastebin.com/NExMZkXh. You mean I shoul use UIButton instead?

Comment: sorry didn´t see that, but try using button.image = UIImage(named: "image.png") on the barButton instead of using setBackButtonBackgroundImage