# Swift strange back button text in iphone plus

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, button, navigationbar

[image]

Please take a look at my screenshot, the blue "Back" text always show on iphone plus (6s plus, 7 plus for both simulator and real device) . It does not show on smaller screen iphone. I tried lot of way to hide/change it from present/previous controller but no luck.

So why does it work on smaller iphone but not the plus one ?

Can anyone help me:(. Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func filter(_ sender: Any) {
    let view:FilterViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FilterViewController") as! FilterViewController
    view.superVC = self
    view.currentFilter = currentFilter
    self.setLeftCloseNavigation()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
}

func setLeftCloseNavigation(){
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.mask = nil

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "icon_close")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "icon_close")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

And here is the viewDidLoad in pushed controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    statusBar = UIColor.black
    setResetNavigation() }

func setResetNavigation(){
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false

    let skipButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 30))
    skipButton.setTitle("Reset all".localized(), for: .normal)
    skipButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    skipButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HJGothamMedium", size: 16)
    skipButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(resetAllClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    let skip = UIBarButtonItem(customView: skipButton)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = skip
}
```

This is the view hierarchy

[image]

Comment: can you show some code

Comment: inspect your view in storyboard and remove that button.

Comment: is this presentViewController ?

Comment: no @KKRocks , this is the view controller after push

Comment: @Bhupat I added few code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this function  :

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
          setResetNavigation()
          self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = ""
    }
```

[image: navigation bar in iPhone 7S]

Comment: thanks but I don't want to remove it, just want to remove the text

Comment: yes I tried this too, it works on smaller iphone, but not the plus one :(

Comment: just a min. i try this in 7s

Comment: yes I'm using auto layout, this is FilterViewController , was pushed from a controller that is child of tabBarController

Comment: can you give me TeamViewer ?

Comment: i think issue in your auto Layout

Comment: what happen when you check on iPhone 7 button also hide ?

Comment: I invited you in hangout, I'm at office too

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

**Or Check your storyboard it will remain**

Comment: thanks but I don't want to hide, just want to remove the text

Answer (score 0):

Use the below line to remove the text

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried but it didn't work :(. I placed this in both previous controller (before push) and in presenting controller (viewdidload, viewdidappear)

Comment: what is that cross.if its a button see if you mistakenly put the name Back to that button along with a cross image

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect your UI hierarchy and if found related view then remove that view :

You can also invoke the view debugger by choosing View UI Hierarchy from the process view options menu in the debug navigator, or by choosing **Debug > View Debugging > Capture View Hierarchy**.

Comment: Please take a look at the screenshot of view hierarchy I just added

Answer (score 0):

From below code you can set backButton text colour to any colour you want.You can simply set backButton to `clear` textColor. So, It won't be visible when it presents.

```
 UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.classForCoder() as! UIAppearanceContainer.Type]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
```

**Update:** If you want to go for a different approach.Check this post [How to customize the navigation back symbol and navigation back text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546132/how-to-customize-the-navigation-back-symbol-and-navigation-back-text/43556837#43556837) and accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the back text you need to set navigation item title to space character on the view controller that pushes the presented view controller:

```
self.navigationItem.title = " "
```

Be aware you have to set it on the previous view controller and not on top most one. Also you have to set a space character and not an empty string !!!

Also you can do this directly on storyboard

[image]