# reduce left space and right space from navigation bar left and right bar button item

Tags: ios, xcode, navigationbar

I am adding two custom buttons on navigation bar.
one at left and other at right.
I am successfully done with it,

but I failed to reduce the space between the starting point and frame of buttons.

I tried a lot, also gave the negative value of x, still didn't helped.
Here is the code for buttons

```
-(void)addLeftButton
{
    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    aButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [aButton setTitle:@"H" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40, 40);
    [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:aBarButtonItem];
}

-(void)addRightButton
{
    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    aButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [aButton setTitle:@"B" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40, 40);
    [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:aBarButtonItem];
}
```

Also tried using

```
aBarButtonItem.width = -16;
```

but didn't helped.

How to achieve this...?
Thanks in advance...

These are the some links that I preferred but didn't helped much
[How to Edit Empty Spaces of Left, Right UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationBar [iOS 7]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914812/how-to-edit-empty-spaces-of-left-right-uibarbuttonitem-in-uinavigationbar-ios)

[How to Edit Empty Spaces of Left, Right UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationBar [iOS 7]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914812/how-to-edit-empty-spaces-of-left-right-uibarbuttonitem-in-uinavigationbar-ios)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                                           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                                                           target:nil action:nil];
    negativeSpacer.width = -16;
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:negativeSpacer,yourbutton, nil] animated:YES];
```

Use like that.

Comment: Hi Yusuf, thanks It works, previously I was adding UIButton directly over setLeftBarButtonItems.
now its working fine
thanks

Comment: for iphone 6 and 6 plus you must use different space.

Comment: @Yusufterzi, For me, I would like to add space to the left bar button (Back button). How can I achieve this?

Comment: i need swift 4 version

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Swift version:

```
let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem()
negativeSpacer.width = -16

let hamburgerButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "hamburgerMenu")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal),
                                              style: .plain,
                                              target: self,
                                              action: #selector(menuButtonPressed))

navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([negativeSpacer, hamburgerButton], animated: true)
```