# Manual UINavigationBar layout issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout, interface-builder

I'm currently creating a screen in which I use a UINavigationBar. When setting up the constraints, I have its leading margin = Superview's leading margin - 20, which renders in IB like so

[image: constraints]

When I add a UIBarButtonItem to the left (programmatically, or in IB), the button is rendered far too close to the left edge:

[image: odd]

Am I doing something wrong here?

Here are the constraints for this scene:

[image: constraints]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *UIBarButtonItem* drag *UIButton* via IB.

It will automatically create UI-components hierarchy like on picture bellow.

Then you'll be able to change content / title / image insets of button or alignment.

[image]

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added a `UIBarButtonItem.FixedSpace` to my `UINavigationItem` as follows:

```
    let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let editButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Edit, target: self, action: "toggleEditing")
    spacer.width = 6.0

    var leftItems = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    leftItems.append(spacer)
    leftItems.append(editButton)
    navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems(leftItems, animated: false)
```

Source: [How to Edit Empty Spaces of Left, Right UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationBar [iOS 7]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914812/how-to-edit-empty-spaces-of-left-right-uibarbuttonitem-in-uinavigationbar-ios)