# UINavigationbar Items out of position

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am having issues trying to figure why navigation bar items are out of place--squeezed to the ends.

see https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8bNRC27tztoTkZwamVlSllMNjA/view
 There isn't anything online that address this. My view hierarchy is

`pageviewcontroller -> navViewController -> VC1`.

I am able to solve the problem but removing this line

```
addChildViewController(pageViewController)
```

in the pageviewcontroller class but I need that for the pageviewcontroller to operate properly. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

App delegate:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {



        let PageVC = PageViewController()


        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window!.rootViewController = PageVC
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

Full pageviewcontroller code:

```
  import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate{
        var viewControllerList = [UIViewController]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let vc1 = IntroViewController()
        let vc2 = CamViewController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1)
        let navigationController2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc2)
        viewControllerList = [navigationController,navigationController2]
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self

        let firstViewController = viewControllerList.first
            self.setViewControllers([firstViewController!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.index(of: viewController) else {return nil}
        let previousIndex = vcIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {return nil}
        guard viewControllerList.count > previousIndex else {return nil}

        return viewControllerList[previousIndex]

    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.index(of: viewController) else {return nil}

        let nextIndex = vcIndex + 1

        guard viewControllerList.count != nextIndex else { return nil}

        guard  viewControllerList.count > nextIndex else { return nil }

        return viewControllerList[nextIndex]

    }
```

Comment: If your page view controller's frame is the entire bounds, why do you even need this other View Controller in the first place? 
Your hierarchy looks like
 Unnecessary VC --> PageVC --> NavController --> VC1.


Why do you need the unnecessary VC?

Comment: Good question. My ideal approach would have been to just subclass pageVC rather than to create it in another VC however I couldnt figure how to set the transition style of the pageVC if subclassed.  This line `let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)` accomplishes that if I create a PageVC within another VC. hope that makes sense. But I understand how its completely unnecessary. Nevertheless, I thought that was the issue but the same problem still exists

Comment: I'm sorry for taking the tangential path, but I think I can avoid this by removing the unnecessary VC. Is this unnecessary VC your app's initial screen? Do you use storyboards or code?

Comment: I guess I am not understanding where you are finding this unnecessary VC? The pageVC is the root VC set in the appdelegate. I have updated the question to include the full app delegate and pageVC code. I created all viewcontrollers in code. The hierarchy should be appdelegate -> pageVC -> VC1

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I do not see the line addChildViewController() now. Can you point where you were initially adding it?

Comment: I only needed to add the line addChildViewController(pageVC) if the PageVC was being created in another VC. Because the updated code shows that pageVC is being subclassed, I do not need to add that line. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Ohkay.. What I was referring to as the unnecessary VC, is what you mentioned as "created in another VC".. Do you still have any other probs?

Comment: Ok. yeah I took your advice and removed the unnecessary VC and just subclassed the pageViewController. Still having the issue of nav items in wrong position though.

Comment: Can you post code on where you add the UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: Ok. I think I seemed to have solved it. To troubleshoot further, I created an empty project with just the pageViewController, VC1. Everything worked. The reason why it worked is because this empty project has the Main Storyboard. As I said, I was making all of my ViewControllers without storyboards. I simply added a storyboard into my project and everything was working. I am still not sure why this was the issue. The app delegate code with the storyboard changed to 

let PageVC = PageViewController()
window!.rootViewController = PageVC

which is different from what I posted.

Comment: its weird  how the adding the storyboard file was the fix even though I am not even using it.  Maybe be I was setting up the window wrong?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you check by setting the frame of the PageViewController in your previous code?

Comment: I am not sure how or if I can even set the frame of the PageViewController. Its the root viewcontroller so the frame is automatically set to the frame of the window.  I checked by print(view.bounds.size) and it shows the default screen size.

Comment: Ohkay.. It does seem out of my knowledge then. This is supposed to work, the way I see it. But, I may be missing something.

Comment: No worries. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the edits to the question. If you still find the issue and don't want to add the UIBarButtonItem piece of code, follow the below answer, **but instead of negative spacing, give a positive one**:
[How to Edit Empty Spaces of Left, Right UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationBar [iOS 7]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914812/how-to-edit-empty-spaces-of-left-right-uibarbuttonitem-in-uinavigationbar-ios)

This is more of a hack. I can give a clearer answer if you can post the piece of code requested :)

Do give an upvote for that answer too :)