# Strange offset on right bar button item

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I encountered a strange problem on the `rightBarButtonItem` of `UINavigationController`. The margin of the button disappears on `iOS7`, so it looks like this:

[image]

At first, I thought it was some mistakes in my `UINavigationController` related categories, but I removed all my customisation code and all the header files of categories, and simply use a UINavigationController and an empty view controller.

In `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

VCTestViewController *vc = [[[VCTestViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
UINavigationController *nc = [[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc]autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = nc;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In `VCTestViewController.m -> viewDidLoad`

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"hello" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```

The problem still exists(as shown above). I can't figure out what is wrong. Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: Any code you could share?

Comment: Do you get storyboard warnings?

Comment: @JasonCoco I don't use storyboard in this project.

Comment: @Cyrille Just some simplest code.

Comment: @WakoM have you tried with my below code ?

Comment: @WakoM Look at 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233591/custom-uibarbuttonitem-alignment-off-with-ios7 and 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914812/how-to-edit-empty-spaces-of-left-right-uibarbuttonitem-in-uinavigationbar-in-io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out what happened.

The link given by βhargavḯ is not the solution of my problem, but it's the cause of my problem. One of my colleagues wrote a category of `UINavigationItem` to narrow the empty space in iOS7. He then used method swizzling to exchanged the system method `setRightBarButtonItem:` with his own method. I didn't realise this.

So I think method swizzling would be extremely dangerous if you exchange the system methods with your own methods.

Answer (score 2):

you can share your line of code if it's not working:

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)rightNavBarButton
{
    UIButton *filterBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [filterBtn setTitle:@"hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    filterBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,40,27);
    [filterBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(getFriendsList) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *filterNavBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:filterBtn];
    return filterNavBarItem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but it's not what I expect. This problem doesn't occur in my other projects, and I have removed every extra code, but this problem still exists. I'd like to figure out why this happens.

Comment: Have you set any navigation title view ?. add background image and check the co-ordinate of UIBarButton Item