# uibarbutton item is not properly aligned in the custom toolbar placed in navigationcontroller item .. in IOS 7?

Tags: iphone

> i addded  UIBarButtonItem *addBarButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] >initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertData)];
>   in the toolbar but + button is not getting proper alignment ?

Comment: Please explain your problem in detail.

Comment: actually i created a custom toolbar and added uibarbuttonitem (addbarbutton ) and self.editbarbutton item okk... edit button is appeared middle of the toolbar but addbarbutton is appeared in lower part of toolbar so here my code of uibarbuttonitem

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *addBarButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] >initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertData)];

Comment: So you are facing this problem in which iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace items to your toolbar, to the left and right of your items

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace, settingsButton,deleteButton,addButton, flexibleSpace, nil]];
[flexibleSpace release];
```

Adding these as you would any other toolbar items will distribute space evenly between the two of them

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i createad a custom toolbar and added two uibarbuttonitem ok and also set toolbar to the rightbarbutton of the navigationitem ?     UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180.0,20, 100, 30)];
        NSArray *items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:addBarButton,self.editButtonItem,nil];
    [toolBar setItems:items];
    UIBarButtonItem *barItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolBar];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=barItem;

Comment: yes you are facing issue because of there is no spacing between you toolbarbuttobs use above code it will resolve your issue hopefully.

Comment: Check below links may it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233591/custom-uibarbuttonitem-alignment-off-with-ios7  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861201/uibarbuttonitem-with-custom-view-not-properly-aligned-on-ios-7-when-used-as-left

Comment: okk ..thnx for suggesting this link .. let me chk it out first

Comment: You welcome if this info is helpful for you then accept my answer so it will be helpful others too. thanks