# Positioning issue with IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xib, uitabbar

Create UITabbarController with xib for 5.0, which worked fine.
But when app is installed in 4-inch device, tabbar item is misplaced. Attached screenshot.

How this can be fixed. Am using UITabbarController in xib

Thanks in advance,

[image]

Comment: See this link, this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628088/ios-6-app-upgrade-to-ios-7/20628187#20628187

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue with UIBarButton, it only happens with System icons in my case, using custom icons worked fine.

I couldn't find a proper solution, but subclassing the object and changing the frame position of the image after the fact seems to work.

I'll update this if I find a solution that works consistently.

related post:
[iOS UIBarButtonItem allignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293363/ios-uibarbuttonitem-allignments)