# How can I change the position of my navigation bar item in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

[image]

This is my navigation bar, the instance of UINavigationBar. Now, I want the leftBarButtonItem move left, how can i do? The platform is iOS 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps,

Under the bar button item, assist menu. Change the image inset to negative

[image]

Comment: Is that an image? Please share some code details as well

Comment: It is a button, and the barButtonItem's frame is (0,0,44,44)，but it's actual x is not 0. I want to make barButtonItem's x 0.

Comment: I suppose you have added a navigation item -> Left Bar button -> Bar button item? Or you adding something different?

Comment: Bar button item

UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];

Comment: and where are you adding it? Can you share the whole of Navigation bar and the items

Comment: self.leftBarButtonItems = @[item];

Comment: Check this then, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861201/uibarbuttonitem-with-custom-view-not-properly-aligned-on-ios-7-when-used-as-left

Comment: It not works too, I overwritten the navigationBar, a foolish way...Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Ok, if you can share the navigation bar code also, i can surely help

Comment: My navigation bar code is very easy, I new a button firstly, then I init a navigationBarItem with the button, then I put this button to an array, finally assign the array to self.leftBarButtonItems. Just like this,  

UIButton *btn = [UIButton new];
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn]; 
self.leftBarButtonItems = @[item];

Comment: OK, when I have leisure time, I will research this problem, Thank you!